# SQL Query Return MAX of multiple Counts (Age Groups)

Tags: sql, count, max

I'm trying to finish this querie to return only the age group that has the most records:

```
SELECT 
       COUNT(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(YEAR, a.Data_Nasc, GETDATE()) BETWEEN 18 AND 29 THEN a.Data_Nasc END) AS '18-29',
       COUNT(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(YEAR, a.Data_Nasc, GETDATE()) BETWEEN 30 AND 39 THEN a.Data_Nasc END) AS '30-39',
       COUNT(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(YEAR, a.Data_Nasc, GETDATE()) BETWEEN 40 AND 49 THEN a.Data_Nasc END) AS '40-49',
       COUNT(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(YEAR, a.Data_Nasc, GETDATE()) BETWEEN 50 AND 59 THEN a.Data_Nasc END) AS'50-59',
       COUNT(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(YEAR, a.Data_Nasc, GETDATE()) > 60 THEN a.Data_Nasc END) AS '>60'
FROM Cliente a
    JOIN Encomenda b ON b.NIF_Cliente = a.NIF_Cliente
WHERE b.NIF_Inst <> 999999999
```

**At this moment the query returns this:**

```
18-29 30-39 40-49 50-59  >60
  9     19   11     5     18
```

The age group with the most records is 30-39, so it would be just the one that wanted to return.

Can anyone help figure out what the best method to solve?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
       sum(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(YEAR, a.Data_Nasc, GETDATE()) BETWEEN 18 AND 29 THEN 1 END) AS '18-29',
       sum(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(YEAR, a.Data_Nasc, GETDATE()) BETWEEN 30 AND 39 THEN 1 END) AS '30-39',
       sum(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(YEAR, a.Data_Nasc, GETDATE()) BETWEEN 40 AND 49 THEN 1 END) AS '40-49',
       sum(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(YEAR, a.Data_Nasc, GETDATE()) BETWEEN 50 AND 59 THEN 1 END) AS'50-59',
       sum(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(YEAR, a.Data_Nasc, GETDATE()) > 60 THEN 1 END) AS '>60'
FROM Cliente a
    JOIN Encomenda b ON b.NIF_Cliente = a.NIF_Cliente
WHERE b.NIF_Inst <> 999999999
```